# In an ASP.Net 4.0 GridView column show date 180 days from date in another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview

Here are the relevant columns of my GridView:

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainStartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="TrainStartDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainEndDate" HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="TrainEndDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False" ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="SuccessfulCompleter" HeaderText="Successful Completer" SortExpression="SuccessfulCompleter" ReadOnly="True" >
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#6666FF" />
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="180 Day Target&nbsp;Date" SortExpression="XDayTargetDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("XDayTargetDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("TrainEndDate").ToString())) ? "No End Date Available" : Eval("TrainEndDate", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

In place of Eval("TrainEndDate", "{0:d}") these are some of the ways I've tried to add 180 days to TrainEndDate:

```
Eval("TrainEndDate", "{0:d}") + 180
DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 180, Eval("TrainEndDate"))
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("TrainEndDate")).AddDays(180)
```

Of course none of those worked.

In addition to the already included check for IsNullOrEmpty, I also need to check the column, "SuccessfulCompleter", and only display TrainEndDate plus 180 days if SuccessfulCompleter contains "Yes", else remain blank (display "").

If this can all be done in the "Text='<%# %>'" of the ItemTemplate that's what I'd prefer.  Else, a C# function in the code behind is okay if complete and perhaps with a little explanation.  I'm no C# expert.  ;-)

Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I have part of the solution.  This will display the date 180 days from TrainEndDate.  But, I'm still working on only displaying it if "SuccessfulCompleter" is "Yes."

Comment: Alright, I have rest of the logic figured out now, too.<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("TrainEndDate").ToString())) ? "No End Date Available" : Eval("SuccessfulCompleter").ToString() != "Yes" ? "-" : DateTime.Parse(Eval("TrainEndDate", "{0:d}")).AddDays(180).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: You can post an answer to your question and accept it. It will make clear that the problem is solved, and it will help other people looking for a solution to the same problem. Code in comment is not easy to read.